# InputStream closed unexpectedly while using Jersey MultiPart file upload & Server-Sent Events (SSE)

Tags: asynchronous, file-upload, jersey, multipart, server-sent-events

I'm using Jersey Multipart for uploading file to the server via Rest API. In the resource method, I accessed the file content via InputStream. I want to return the uploaded file size to the client with [EventOutput](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/sse/EventOutput.html) using [SSE](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html#overview) so the client easily get the uploaded file size directly from upload resource method.
I'm using Jersey as JAX-RS implementation in java with Grizzly Http server. Here is my code:

```
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
@Consumes("multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8")
public EventOutput upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
                          @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition) {
    final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
    try {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int read = -1;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder
                            = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                    OutboundEvent event = null;
                    long totalRead = 0, lastReadMB = 0;

                    while ((read = file.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        totalRead += read;
                        if (lastReadMB != (totalRead / (1024 * 1024))) {
                            lastReadMB = totalRead / (1024 * 1024);
                            event = eventBuilder.name("uploaded").data(Long.class, totalRead).build();
                            eventOutput.write(event);
                        }
                    }
                    event = eventBuilder.name("uploaded").data(Long.class, totalRead).build();
                    eventOutput.write(event);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Error when writing the event.", e);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        eventOutput.close();
                    } catch (Exception ioClose) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(
                                "Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return eventOutput;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.toString(), e);
    }
    throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).
            entity("something happened").build());
}
```

​
The problem is when my resource method return EventOutput as a response and request processing thread back to the I/O container, the InputStream closed and the processing thread can't access to the uploaded file. Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when writing the event.
    at com.WebService.ContentService$1.run(ContentService.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.WeakDataFile.read(WeakDataFile.java:115)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataFile.read(DataFile.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.FileData.read(FileData.java:69)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream.fetch(DataHead.java:265)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream.read(DataHead.java:219)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at com.WebService.ContentService$1.run(ContentService.java:181)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:557)
    at org.jvnet.mimepull.WeakDataFile.read(WeakDataFile.java:112)
    ... 7 more
```

​
1- What's the problem in the code? Why InputStream is closed in the middle of the file transfer?
2- Is there any alternative way to return the uploaded file size to the client in server side? (REQUIREMENT: the upload resource method must  handle upload file asynchronously in different thread)

Comment: I don't see a need for SSE. Just run in [async mode](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10208)

Comment: @peeskillet , I want to notify the client how much has been uploaded to the server via the same HTTP connection which the client used for uploading the file. In Async mode, client will be notified  after upload completed.

Comment: @peeskillet I want to client be able to show a upload progress bar with the SSE events (uploaded-event) received from upload resource method.